# Как сделать переход обратно в Python telebot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Уважаемые, я пытаюсь сделать тг бота, где я учитываю долги и оплаты. Я очень мучаюсь с тем, что я после просмотра списка долгов или введения оплат не могу сделать кнопку которая бы переходила обратно в старт. Подскажите мне пожалуйста, как это исправить.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

token = telebot.TeleBot('---------')
chelZapis = None


@token.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(mainParam):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baza (id int auto_increment primary key, nikChela varchar(50), money int)')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bts = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    bts.add(types.KeyboardButton("Запись"), types.KeyboardButton("Чекнуть долги"))

    vopros = token.send_message(mainParam.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=bts)
    token.register_next_step_handler(vopros, proverka)

def proverka(message):
    if message.text == "Запись":
        vopros = token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ник человека:')
        token.register_next_step_handler(vopros, vvodChela)
    elif message.text == "Чекнуть долги":
        vopros = token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Список долгов:')
        conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM baza')
        a = cur.fetchall()
        info = ''
        for i in a:
            info += f'{i[1]}, {i[2]}\n'
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        token.send_message(message.chat.id, info)

    else:
        token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пошел нахуй с такими запросами')

def vvodChela(message):
    global chelZapis
    chelZapis = message.text.strip()
    vopros = token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько должен?')
    token.register_next_step_handler(vopros, vvodDeneg)

def vvodDeneg(message):
    dolg = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO baza (nikChela, money) VALUES ("%s", "%s")' % (chelZapis, dolg))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Запись сделала успешно')


"""
@token.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def nachalo(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Запись':
            token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ник чела:')
            token.register_next_step_handler(message)

            token.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько должен?')
            token.register_next_step_handler(message)



            conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baza (id int auto_increment primary key, nikChela varchar(50), money int)')
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
            conn.close()

            bts = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            BtnZapis = types.KeyboardButton("Запись")
            BtnVivod = types.KeyboardButton("Чекнуть долги")
            bts.add(BtnZapis, BtnVivod)

        elif message.text == 'Чекнуть долги':
            conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute('SELECT * FROM baza')
            a = cur.fetchall()

            info = ''
            for i in a:
                info += f'{i[1]}, {i[2]}\n'

            cur.close()
            conn.close()
            token.send_message(message.chat.id, info)

            conn = sqlite3.connect('dbOplat.sql')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS baza (id int auto_increment primary key, nikChela varchar(50), money int)')
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
            conn.close()

            bts = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
            BtnZapis = types.KeyboardButton("Запись")
            BtnVivod = types.KeyboardButton("Чекнуть долги")
            bts.add(BtnZapis, BtnVivod)

"""

token.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Так же если не сложно я бы хотел спросить, как сделать такую штуку: если я ввожу ник человека который уже есть и ввожу +сумма то к его долгу добавляется сумма, а если -сумма, то вычитается и если в итоге там оказывается 0 то запись удаляется